Managing session timeouts with AWS Cognito/Amplify
I am using AWS Cognito/Amplify (v6) to manage user authentication and I'd like to implement session timeouts. I already implemented a timer on Angular front-end to start a timer after a user is logged in to log them out automatically after 30 min. Now, I need to extend user's session each time user takes an action (i.e. a call is made to my REST API). I can reset timer easily after each action, however, a new access token is needed each time also.
Currently, logged in users get kicked out after 30 min regardless of them being idle or not which is bad user experience. I don't want to rely on refresh tokens as then users may end staying logged in for a long time. Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?
